# Android Storage - Cannot READ directory files outside application's directory even with permissions setted

Tags: java, android, permissions, storage

Trying to get files list under external storage directory results in no file even if they exists and permissions to read the directory has been set.

Given the following sample:

*MainActivity.java*

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        File ed = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

        File[] fs = ed.listFiles();
        Log.i(ed.getAbsolutePath(), (fs != null ? fs.length : "no") + " files found");

    }
}
```

*AndroidManifest.xml*

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.test">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

*app/build.gradle*

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.test"
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 23
...
```

Tested on a phisical device (Nexus 5, with Android 6.0.1), this is the logcat:

> 06-15 11:42:17.309 16732-16732/com.test I//storage/emulated/0: no files found

no other warning or error.

Via **adb** shell tool I can see the following subdirectories with their permissions

```
$ cd /storage/emulated/
$ ls -l 
drwxrwx--x root     sdcard_rw          1970-03-05 14:05 Alarms
drwxrwx--x root     sdcard_rw          2015-09-10 23:44 Android
drwxrwx--x root     sdcard_rw          2015-08-11 18:40 BDArenaConnector
drwxrwx--x root     sdcard_rw          2015-02-03 14:14 DCIM
drwxrwx--x root     sdcard_rw          2016-06-14 10:59 Download
drwxrwx--x root     sdcard_rw          2015-09-15 11:48 MOGO_AUDIANCE
drwxrwx--x root     sdcard_rw          2015-06-19 11:49 Manga Mobile
drwxrwx--x root     sdcard_rw          2015-10-19 21:02 Memes
drwxrwx--x root     sdcard_rw          1970-03-05 14:05 Movies
drwxrwx--x root     sdcard_rw          2016-05-24 11:01 Music
drwxrwx--x root     sdcard_rw          2015-01-12 20:43 Notifications
drwxrwx--x root     sdcard_rw          2015-11-24 19:19 PerfectViewer
drwxrwx--x root     sdcard_rw          2016-06-01 16:58 Pictures
drwxrwx--x root     sdcard_rw          1970-03-05 14:05 Podcasts
drwxrwx--x root     sdcard_rw          2015-04-30 10:16 ROMs
drwxrwx--x root     sdcard_rw          2015-01-12 20:36 Ringtones
drwxrwx--x root     sdcard_rw          2015-08-10 18:57 SKMaps
drwxrwx--x root     sdcard_rw          2015-09-15 11:48 ShareSDK
drwxrwx--x root     sdcard_rw          2015-08-16 10:40 Telegram
drwxrwx--x root     sdcard_rw          2015-05-29 21:36 TuneIn Radio
drwxrwx--x root     sdcard_rw          2016-05-27 00:08 WhatsApp
drwxrwx--x root     sdcard_rw          2015-05-20 09:21 airdroid
drwxrwx--x root     sdcard_rw          2016-05-31 16:59 backups
drwxrwx--x root     sdcard_rw          2015-11-10 14:42 bluetooth
drwxrwx--x root     sdcard_rw          2015-11-15 19:43 com.facebook.katana
drwxrwx--x root     sdcard_rw          2015-08-10 18:44 > com.facebook.orca
drwxrwx--x root     sdcard_rw          2015-09-15 11:51 ktplay
drwxrwx--x root     sdcard_rw          2015-04-23 20:30 media
drwxrwx--x root     sdcard_rw          1970-03-05 14:04 obb
drwxrwx--x root     sdcard_rw          2015-02-07 19:11 panoramas
drwxrwx--x root     sdcard_rw          2015-06-19 11:53 smart-tools
drwxrwx--x root     sdcard_rw          2015-09-28 12:56 wp
```

I know this directory should be available for applications to be read because some other applications do that without any problem (like Astro File Manager or PerfectViewer).

Comment: for which os version you are testing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need runtime permission while compiling against again 6.0

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        private static final int REQUEST_RUNTIME_PERMISSION = 1;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

             checkPremission();
            }


         void checkPremission() {
                //select which permission you want
                final String permission = Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE;
                    // if in fragment use getActivity()
                if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(ActivityName.this, permission)
                        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(ActivityName.this, permission)) {

                    } else {
                        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(ActivityName.this, new String[]{permission}, REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION);
                    }
                } else {
                    // you have permission go ahead
                    File ed = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
                    File[] fs = ed.listFiles();
                    Log.i(ed.getAbsolutePath(), (fs != null ? fs.length : "no") + " files found");
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
                switch (requestCode) {
                    case REQUEST_RUNTIME_PERMISSION:
                        final int numOfRequest = grantResults.length;
                        final boolean isGranted = numOfRequest == 1
                                && PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED == grantResults[numOfRequest - 1];
                        if (isGranted) {
                            // you have permission go ahead
                           File ed = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

                           File[] fs = ed.listFiles();
                           Log.i(ed.getAbsolutePath(), (fs != null ? fs.length : "no") + " files found");
                        }else{
                            // you dont have permission show toast
                        }
                        break;
                    default:
                        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
                }
            }
}
```